# read a property from another property(multiple levels) in java

Tags: java, properties

My situation is like this

I am having a property file like this

```
url.DEV.a=devlocalhost  
url.QA.a=qalocalhost  
env=DEV
totalurl=${url.${env}.a}
```

Here i am expecting totalurl as **devlocalhost**

how can i do this in property file.

Comment: i need to this in a properties file not from java class

Comment: how is this related to xml? or to java?

Comment: env value will be dynamic. So that I can't replace env value..

Answer (score 0):

The following is a class that I cleaned up from a open source project I work with. If can't be used as it is, it can atleast be a starting point for your exploration.

```
package snippet;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PropertyReplace {

    /**
     * Replaces java properties in the properties of the form %&lt;java
     * property&gt; with the java property value.
     * 
     * @param properties
     *            , Properties where the replacement takes place
     */
    public static void replaceEnviron(Properties properties) {
        Enumeration<Object> enumeration = properties.keys();
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
            String value = properties.getProperty(key);
            System.out.println("Finding value for key " + key);
            String updatedValue = getUpdatedValue(value, properties);
            if (updatedValue == null)
                updatedValue = "";
            properties.setProperty(key, updatedValue);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the value for a given MPF property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            , the original value
     * @param properties
     *            , properties from which the replacements are taken
     * @return the modified value
     */
    private static String getUpdatedValue(String value, Properties properties) {
        System.out.println("Value = " + value);
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^%]*(%[^%]*%).*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
        while (m.matches()) {
            String var = m.group(1);
            String varValue = getUpdatedValue(properties.getProperty(var.substring(1, var.length() - 1)), properties);
            if (varValue == null) {
                varValue = System.getProperty(var.substring(1, var.length() - 1), null);
                if (varValue == null) {
                    varValue = System.getenv(var.substring(1, var.length() - 1));
                    if (varValue == null)
                        varValue = "";
                }
            }
            value = value.replaceAll(var, varValue);
            m = p.matcher(value);
        }
        System.out.println("Return: " + value);
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        // url.DEV.a=devlocalhost
        // url.QA.a=qalocalhost
        // env=DEV
        // totalurl=${url.${env}.a}

        props.setProperty("url.DEV.a", "devlocalhost");
        props.setProperty("url.QA.a", "qalocalhost");
        props.setProperty("env", "DEV");
        props.setProperty("totalurlX", "url.%env%.a");
        props.setProperty("totalurl", "%totalurlX%");

        replaceEnviron(props);

        System.out.println(props);

    }

}
```