# Reading property from another property

Tags: properties, properties-file

I am having a property file like this

```
url.DEV.a=devlocalhost  
url.QA.a=qalocalhost  
env=DEV
```

To get url I am using below property. But I can't able to get correct value.

```
totalurl=${url.${env}.a}
```

Here i am expecting totalurl as **devlocalhost**

how can i do this in property file.

Comment: Exact duplicate of one of your other questions: [read a property from another property(multiple levels) in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202307/read-a-property-from-another-propertymultiple-levels-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can check here :
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide_v1.10/howto_basicfeatures.html#Variable_Interpolation

Could you give more details, why you need such configuration ?
It's not easier for you to use a common file where you store the common properties ?

Comment: This url is not helping to my requirement. "env" property will come with different values like DEV,QA,PROD..etc. That value I will get in property file. So I need to replace that value.

Comment: At the end of the page, they explains how to customize the interpretation of variable. What you can do, is override this class (StrLookup) and parse file name, then read variable value from parsed file.